# is this use of eval in a node server a bad idea?

Tags: node.js, eval

I want to create an object dynamically in node. To do that i used a code like this. 
Is this use of eval in a node server a bad idea?

```
var a1 = require(./a1.js),
    a2 = require(./a2.js),
    ...
    aN = require(./aN.js);

    function createObj(pObjName, pObjValue){
        var tmp = new eval(pObjName)(pObjValue);
        //where pObjName is a1 or a1 or .... or aN
    }
```

Comment: It's hard to guess what you want to achieve, but It's very likely there are better ways to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what you're showing, there's no need to use `eval`:

```
const Classes = {
  a1 : require('./a1'),
  a2 : require('./a2'),
  ...
};

function createObj(pObjName, pObjValue){
  var tmp = new Classes[pObjName](pObjValue);
  ...
}
```

Comment: Even `new (require('./' + pObjName))(pObjValue)` would suffice, since resolved dependencies get memoized and consecutive calls don't have any extra overhead.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts yeah that would be another good solution :) (although depending on where `pObjName` is coming from, it may need to be sanitized first)

Comment: I had thought of this alternative. Since you suggest me too, I will adopt this solution. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you want to create objects with a set of properties?

You might want to look at the [Object.create()-method](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save yourself the time of declaring all of those dependencies, you could even write a function without using `eval` that handles the case even more efficiently:

```
function createObj(pObjName, pObjValue) {
  var tmp = new (require('./' + pObjName))(pObjValue);
  // ...
}
```

Please note that this is only safe if `createObj()` is guaranteed to be invoked with a `pObjName` that is what you expect, otherwise you'll need to validate it first, possibly something like this:

```
function createObj(pObjName, pObjValue) {
  if (!/^a\d$/.test(pObjName)) {
    throw new TypeError('invalid name')
  }

  var tmp = new (require('./' + pObjName))(pObjValue);
  // ...
}
```